# Lebesgue measure of sets of empty interior

Tags: lebesgue-measure

There is a proposition to the effect that if the Lebesgue measure of a set is zero, then it is a set of empty interior. Does the converse also hold true, *i.e.* is the Lebesgue measure of any set of empty interior zero? If not, is there a straightforward counterexample?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$? It has empty interior but it has infinite measure because $\mathbb{Q}$ has measure zero (it is countable).

Answer (score 8):

[Fat Cantor sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) provide another set of counter examples.